# Do I need a CURSOR for this?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to step through a table and update an attribute based on the below query.

When I run the below, it set's all values to 52, so it is recognising the first case and applying to all values. If I remove the count from the select statements of the case I get an error saying it returns more than 1 row.
Each of the select statements are correct in returning the items that need to be updated when I run them individually. For instance, the select statement in the first case has 41 rows (products) that need updating to value '52', then another 14 rows for the second case, 35 for the next and 26 for the next.

I am going around in circles and I have absolutely no idea how to apply the value to the rows based on each of the select statements in the cases. I don't think a case statement is correct either now. Please help.

My thinking is along 'for each row in select statement update value = x where t1.taxonomy= 'pa_supplier and t1.product_id = table2.product_id where table2.sku = table4.VendorStockCode'. How to write this in mySQL though? Stumped...

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.term_id = 
(
    CASE
        WHEN 
            (
SELECT COUNT(VendorStockCode) FROM table4 t4
JOIN table5 t5 WHERE t4.VendorStockCode= t5.Manufacture_Code AND EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM table2 WHERE table4.VendorStockCode = table2.sku) AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t5.Stock_qty <= 0
            ) > 0
        THEN '52'
        WHEN 
            (
SELECT COUNT(VendorStockCode) FROM table4 t4
JOIN table5 t5 WHERE t4.VendorStockCode= t5.Manufacture_Code AND EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM table2 WHERE table4.VendorStockCode = table2.sku) AND t4.StockAvailable <= 0 AND t5.Stock_qty > 0
            ) > 0
        THEN '51'
        WHEN 
            (
SELECT COUNT(VendorStockCode) FROM table4 t4
JOIN table5 t5 WHERE t4.VendorStockCode= t5.Manufacture_Code AND EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM table2 WHERE table4.VendorStockCode = table2.sku) AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t5.Stock_qty > 0 AND CAST(t4.DealerEx as decimal(10,2)) > cast(t5.ExTax as decimal(10,2))
            ) > 0
        THEN '51'
                WHEN 
            (
SELECT COUNT(VendorStockCode) FROM table4 t4
JOIN table5 t5 WHERE t4.VendorStockCode= t5.Manufacture_Code AND EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM table2 WHERE table4.VendorStockCode = table2.sku) AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t5.Stock_qty > 0 AND CAST(t4.DealerEx as decimal(10,2)) <= cast(t5.ExTax as decimal(10,2))
            ) > 0
        THEN '52'
        ELSE t1.term_id
    END
)
WHERE t1.taxonomy= 'pa_supplier';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Try the query below it might need some syntax fixes:

```
WITH
  trow AS (
Select * from table1 t1,
WHERE t1.taxonomy= 'pa_supplier')
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.term_id = 
(
    CASE
        WHEN 
            (
SELECT COUNT(VendorStockCode) FROM table4 t4
JOIN table5 t5 WHERE t4.VendorStockCode= t5.Manufacture_Code AND EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM table2 WHERE table4.VendorStockCode = table2.sku) AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t5.Stock_qty <= 0
            ) > 0
        THEN '52'
        WHEN 
            (
SELECT COUNT(VendorStockCode) FROM table4 t4
JOIN table5 t5 WHERE t4.VendorStockCode= t5.Manufacture_Code AND EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM table2 WHERE table4.VendorStockCode = table2.sku) AND t4.StockAvailable <= 0 AND t5.Stock_qty > 0
            ) > 0
        THEN '51'
        WHEN 
            (
SELECT COUNT(VendorStockCode) FROM table4 t4
JOIN table5 t5 WHERE t4.VendorStockCode= t5.Manufacture_Code AND EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM table2 WHERE table4.VendorStockCode = table2.sku) AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t5.Stock_qty > 0 AND CAST(t4.DealerEx as decimal(10,2)) > cast(t5.ExTax as decimal(10,2))
            ) > 0
        THEN '51'
                WHEN 
            (
SELECT COUNT(VendorStockCode) FROM table4 t4
JOIN table5 t5 WHERE t4.VendorStockCode= t5.Manufacture_Code AND EXISTS(SELECT sku FROM table2 WHERE table4.VendorStockCode = table2.sku) AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t5.Stock_qty > 0 AND CAST(t4.DealerEx as decimal(10,2)) <= cast(t5.ExTax as decimal(10,2))
            ) > 0
        THEN '52'
            ELSE t1.term_id
        END
    )
INNER JOIN table1 as t1
on trow.product_id=t1.product_id;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, should the INNER JOIN be on table2?
I am currently getting unrecognised statement type (near WITH) which I am trying to work out

Comment: cte alias trow has only a where clause, i have not included table2 since it is not on your code. what if you create a fiddle and share it ? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I was intending on using table2 for each row as it ties the sku numbers in the case statements to the other tables. I haven't used fiddle before but I can give it a go

Comment: ok, I have created this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8f2a8/2
It has all the tables used in the above query with a couple rows of data.

Comment: question have you tried ONLY the update with case statement ? did it work ?

Comment: the update section does not work at all kindly try to fix it

Comment: I am working on it, may take a while. I did run it but has changed everything to '52' so not working as intended. I will try and work it out and come back.

Comment: I have updated the original question to explain it in a different way. I don't know how to fix it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the below to work but takes a very long time to execute, but it is working.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.term_id = 52 WHERE t1.taxonomy= 'pa_supplier' AND t1.product_id IN (
SELECT product_id FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.Manufacture_Code = t2.sku
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.VendorStockCode= t3.Manufacture_Code AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t3.Stock_qty <= 0)

UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.term_id = 51 WHERE t1.taxonomy= 'pa_supplier' AND t1.product_id IN (
SELECT product_id FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.Manufacture_Code = t2.sku
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.VendorStockCode= t3.Manufacture_Code AND t4.StockAvailable <= 0 AND t3.Stock_qty > 0)            

UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.term_id = 51 WHERE t1.taxonomy= 'pa_supplier' AND t1.product_id IN (
SELECT product_id FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.Manufacture_Code = t2.sku
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.VendorStockCode= t3.Manufacture_Code AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t3.Stock_qty > 0 AND CAST(DealerEx as decimal(10,2)) > cast(ExTax as decimal(10,2)))

UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.term_id = 52 WHERE t1.taxonomy= 'pa_supplier' AND t1.product_id IN (
SELECT product_id FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.Manufacture_Code = t2.sku
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.VendorStockCode= t3.Manufacture_Code AND t4.StockAvailable > 0 AND t3.Stock_qty > 0 AND CAST(DealerEx as decimal(10,2)) <= cast(ExTax as decimal(10,2)))
```

Comment: Note table4 is 16MB in size so may be contributing to the long execution time.  I would still like any suggestions to improve the performance is possible